# Iterate into a multidimensional tuple with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, tuples

I'm a beginner in Python and I'm trying to understand how the iterations in for loop work.

I have created a multidimensional tuple that contains integer like below

```
image_dimension = ((820, 312),
               (1500, 500),
               (2480, 520))
```

Now, I would like to use the index of every row of the tuple as an index in a `for` cycle.

I have tried the code `for i in image_dimension:` but clearly, it returns the tuple of every row and not the index

At the moment I'm using the following code to access the positions of the tuple

```
cycles = range(0, 3)
for count in cycles:
    aspect_ratio_x = image_width / image_dimension[count][0]
    to_crop_from_high_and_low = image_dimension[count][1] * aspect_ratio_x

      # do other stuff
```

but instead of using the `range()` function and manually change the element inside it, I would like the `for` loop automatically iterate the row of the tuple.

I know I could use something like `cycles = range(0, len(image_dimension))` but I would like to make it cleaner

Comment: You can just use `for i, j in image_dimension:` (or whatever you want the variables to be called instead of `i` and `j`) to iterate and unpack at the same time. In this example, on the first iteration `i` would be 820 and `j` would be 312. And similarly on later iterations.

Comment: @alani ok that iterates on every single element but I just need the index of the row, not the actual value

Comment: You can combine with `enumerate`: `for index, (i, j) in enumerate(image_dimension):` - although I can't actually see how your existing code is using the index, except to subset the original tuple, so I can't see why you would actually need the index.

Comment: @alani this is what I was looking for! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @alani the solution is to use the `enumerate()` function

```
for index, (i, j) in enumerate(image_dimension):
    aspect_ratio_x = image_width / image_dimension[index][0]
    to_crop_from_high_and_low = image_dimension[index][1] * aspect_ratio_x
```